# Why won't this function work with "formatted" numbers?

Tags: php, function

I have a function that does this...

```
function coefficient_display($coeff){
    if ($coeff == 1){
        return '';
    } elseif ($coeff == -1){
        return '-';
    } else {
        return $coeff;
    }   
}
```

It seems that, if you feed it a "formatted" number, it fails.  Why?

`coefficient_display(1200)` gives **1200**.
`coefficient_display('1200')` gives **1200**.
`coefficient_display(1,200)` fails.

Comment: because `1,200` is not a number, and how are you feeding this?

Comment: `coefficient_display('1,200');`  should work

Comment: So why does coefficient_display('1200') give 1200?  Isn't '1200' a string?

Comment: `coefficient_display(1,200)` means you are passing 2 parameters `1` and `200`

Comment: is not a string, there are 2 arguments provided: 1 and 200

Comment: yes its a string that does not match 1 or -1 so returns 'raw'

Comment: @bansi - which means that `$coeff` has value of 1. Makes sense. So OP can test by passing in `2,200` and if it outputs `2` you nailed it.

Comment: @Anthony you are correct `coefficient_display(2,200)` will return `2` not `2,200`

Comment: @bansi - I know, that's why it's a good test. The OP may not see the issue because `1` outputs `''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because no some "formatted" numbers here: foo(1,200) only 2 arguments 1 and 200.

Try `coefficient_display("1,200")` or `coefficient_display("1.200")`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some explanation for what you are getting.

`coefficient_display('1200')gives 1200.`

PHP data-types are interchangeable so `'1200'(string)` != 1 or -1. thus executes the else part.

`coefficient_display(1,200) fails.`

This is not actually failing this returns the blank string. As the first parameter is 1 `if ($coeff == 1)` is true and it executes `return '';` line. the second parameter `200` is ignored.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1,200 is not a number, try coefficient_display('1,200')
 And change all '==' to '==='